# substr causes segmentation fault

Tags: c++, linux, string

I have the following string :

> B�#012a#016�G�6�)_#014�d%|1401 01
>   000][M00FEB11002FA]_13:40:39,08-30-2012�:�

I coded this simple code to grab the value 1401 located after the |

The problem is when i call substr i get a segmentation fault the code is this:

```
string test = "B�#012a#016�G�6�)_#014�d%|1401 01 000][M00FEB11002FA]_13:40:39,08-30-2012�:�";
    int jj = test.find("]");


for (int j = jj  ; j > 0 ; j--)
{
    if (test.at(j) == '|')
    {
        test = test.substr(j+1);
        test = test.substr(0,test.find_first_of(' '));
    }
}
```

Could somebody say what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: What are the unprintable characters?

Comment: Do you have a typo ? You say you want `|` but your code uses `]` in the `find` call ??

Comment: @mathematician1975 i am searching for the | from the ] position

Comment: @JoachimPileborg the data is decode using aes those bytes are some padding bytes sent by a device.

Comment: You're modifying `test` as you iterate, so `j` is probably becoming invalid (i.e. going out of range).

Comment: You probably want to break out of the loop when you find the string you wanted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The problem is when i call substr i get a segmentation fault the code is this:

No. The segmentation fault is called by your failure to handle exception thrown by `at` since after you’ve modified your string for the first time, the subsequent `at` call will access an index outside of the string bounds.

If you leave the loops after the string modification, it works.

That said, the code can be drastically simplified by replacing the whole outer loop by `string::rfind`, and replacing the two `substr` calls by a single one:

```
int end = test.find("]");
int start = test.rfind("|", end);
test = test.substr(start + 1, test.find(' ', start) - start);
```

(No `find_first_of` needed here either.)

Answer (score 3):

There are two possible problems:

1. When you find the parts you are looking for, you *continue* looping, but now with a different string than what you started with. Add a `break` inside the `if` block.
2. If the unprintable character is a zero (the same as `'\0'`) then the string will only contain one character, the first `'B'`. You then start looping *without checking* if the `find` call returns a valid position, it will actually be `string::npos` if this case is true.